# Understanding how much of your microservice infrastructure should be shared with other business units

Tags: architecture, microservices

Is it generally best to deploy separate microservice infrastructure, including
big components like container schedulers, by team/product?

I get the feeling that this strongly depends on the organization's structure
and culture, much like
[this](http://www.ben-morris.com/should-microservices-share-technologies-and-capabilities/)
article suggests. Our organization is hierarchical, with areas in different
branches in charge of different specialties (database, OS admin, development,
QA all have different managers and even directors). All these areas naturally
have their different priorities and exist with somewhat large knowledge gaps
between them. Still though, the pressure for rapid delivery is felt, both from 
market pressures and also regulatory obligations.

As a software developer, I very much like the idea of *loose coupling* and
believe our team should have its own separate instances of container
management platform. Our team should be multifunctional, capable of delivering
to production ourselves. I can think of several advantages of this approach:

- We would be responsible for the homogeinity of our environments
- Faster iterations
- Risk is spread out over several infrastructure/teams instead of having one
  giant mega instance
- Removal of external teams from the equation when considering an
  internal change/upgrade to your platform

Answer (score 1):

There is always some level of shared infrastructure, if nothing else, at the network level. I think the key is to share infrastructure in such a way so that it doesn't compromise your ability to deploy your microservice independently of other teams. For example, if you share some infrastructure such as a database, then the database team should take responsibility for the management of the server (hardware, replication, monitoring, allocation of resources etc), and the microservice team should take ownership of their database, including the ability to change it's schema. Changes to the infrastructure can still break your microservice e.g. database server version update, but it is less likely you will break the infrastructure by your changes. You also really don't want to be in a position where you need to submit a change request to an external team in order to run a script to update your schema, as that cancels out the key benefit of adopting a microservice architecture. An alternative is to have a structure where each microservice team is allocated a team member who has authority to make timely changes to the infrastructure, but this doesn't necessarily mean that there wont also be delays and conflicts.

What you should definitely try to avoid though, is 'integrating' your microservices via the infrastructure e.g. two distinctly separate microservices using the same database schema/instance. As well as coupling your microservice to the infrastructure, you also tightly couple your microservices, hugely compromising your ability to deploy.

Comment: What do you think about sharing the same instance of container scheduler? That is one question (vociferously) raised here, but I share your fear: `You also really don't want to be in a position where you need to submit a change request to an external team`

Comment: Yes I think it makes sense to share the scheduler, so long as it is setup and managed to enable you to make the decision to deploy independently. It fine to share infrastructure, but not if (a) the power to use it is taken out of your hands or (b) it couples you to other services. There will be times when infrastructure changes will break you though, but that cant be avoided.